# Grouping with descending order and then sorting with descending order

Tags: angularjs, sorting, underscore.js, grouping

How to group data by year and descending order (newer to older) and then inside each group sort items again by descending order?

I'm using angular and underscore.

**fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/xgxfqrgv/1/**

---

output now is:

```
2014
Cranberry

2015
Banana
Apple
```

but it should be:

```
2015
Apple
Banana

2014
Cranberry
```

---

html source:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(year, fulldata) in all | orderBy: 'year':true">
      <br>
      <u>{{year}}</u>
    <div ng-repeat="data in fulldata | orderBy: 'date':true">
        {{data.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js source:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {   
  var _all = [
    { year: 2015, date: "1. 5. 2015", name: "Banana" },
    { year: 2014, date: "1. 10. 2014", name: "Cranberry"},
    { year: 2015, date: "1. 10. 2015", name: "Apple" }
  ];

  $scope.all = _.groupBy(_all, 'year');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function _.groupBy returns an object and you can't order an object using ng-repeat. What you could do is transform the object into an array:

```
$scope.all = _.map( $scope.all, function(data, year){
    return {
        year: year,
        data: data
    }
})
```

and then have the following in the view (the minus before the year signifies a descending order):

```
<div ng-repeat="group in all | orderBy: '-year'">
   <br>
   <u>{{group.year}}</u>
   <div ng-repeat="yearsdata in group.data | orderBy: 'date'">
      {{yearsdata.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xgxfqrgv/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var _all = [{
        year: 2015,
        date: "1. 5. 2015",
        name: "Banana"
    }, {
        year: 2014,
        date: "1. 10. 2014",
        name: "Cranberry"
    }, {
        year: 2015,
        date: "1. 10. 2015",
        name: "Apple"
    }];

    $scope.all = _.groupBy(_all, 'year');
    console.log($scope.all);

    $scope.all[2015] = _.sortBy($scope.all[2015], 'date');
    console.log($scope.all);
}
```

Note: instead of `$scope.all[2015] = _.sortBy($scope.all[2015], 'date');` you should iterate over the properties of the object and apply the sorting. if you want to switch the sort order, just modify it to `$scope.all[2015] = _.sortBy($scope.all[2015], 'date').reverse();`

Comment: I tried your idea, as you can [see in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgxfqrgv/4/), but it's still not complete.

Is there something I am missing?

output now is:
`
    2014
    Cranberry

    2015
    Apple
    Banana
`
but it should be:
`
    2015
    Apple
    Banana

    2014
    Cranberry
`